# JSF 2.0 Primefaces close a dialog in a composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to display a composite component inside a dialog. It works but then how do I close that dialog from the composite component.

```
<p:commandButton value="Display Data Value Assertion Dialog" onclick="dlg2.show();" type="button"/> 
<p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="600" width="800">  
        <tcmt:DataValueAssertion managedBean="#{dataValueAssertionController}"/>
</p:dialog>
```

In my composite component:

```
        <h:commandButton value="Save Assertions">
            <f:ajax listener="#{datatypeAssertionController.saveDatatypeAssertion}"></f:ajax>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:commandLink value="Close">
            <f:ajax listener="#{datatypeAssertionController.closeDatatypeAssertion}"></f:ajax>
        </h:commandLink>
```

When clicking on Save, I want to be able to save the data and close the dialog. When clicking on Cancel, I just want to close the dialog without saving. Both `saveDatatypeAssertion` and `closeDatatypeAssertion` methods are placeholders. I need to find a way to get a reference for the dialog `dlg2` and then call the `hide()` method on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using JSF 2.0.You can do like this:

```
 <h:commandButton value="Save Assertions"  >
  <f:ajax event="click" onevent="dlg2.hide()" listener="#{datatypeAssertionController.saveDatatypeAssertion}" />
 </h:commandButton>

<h:commandLink value="Close" >
      <f:ajax event="click" onevent="dlg2.hide()"  listener="#{datatypeAssertionController.closeDatatypeAssertion}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: The dialog is closed but the listener is not called.

Comment: I got it fixed: `<f:ajax event="click" onevent="dlg2.hide()" listener="#{datatypeAssertionController.saveDataValueAssertion}"></f:ajax>`

Comment: Yeah, you are right.I just make a mistake.I will edit my answer.

Comment: But you can try `actionListener="#{data*.saveDataValueAssertion()}"`,it may be work. I just forget the **()**